# How is charge times velocity equal to rate of change of dipole moment?

Tags: dipole, dipole-moment

I'm reading Feynman Lectures and having trouble understating this part. Suppose a lump of charge is moving in a uniform velocity. All part of the lump is moving in the same velocity $\vec v$. The lump consists of seperate charges and the separation between their center is $d$. Now Feynman says that $q\vec v = \frac{\partial \vec p}{\partial t}$. How can this be true?

If all of the charges are moving in the same velocity then the separation between them won't change and so won't the dipole moment. So how does this equation make sense?

The chapter is 21-4: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_21.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies in here:

> ...we will consider that our wiggling charge q is located near an equal and opposite charge at rest.

This way $\boldsymbol{\dot{p}}=q\boldsymbol{\dot{d}}=q\boldsymbol{v}$ because only one of the two charges of the dipole is moving.